# How to remove hidden quotes

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I've Excel sheet that has few text columns. These text columns are Email Messages. The data from this sheet will be used to send mails.

There data looks fine in Excel but when the message is copied to the Email body quotes are appearing in the beginning and end of the message.

I researched online and found out that these are unwanted characters. I tried removing the `"` using following formula.

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(CLEAN(K1),CHAR(127),""),CHAR(160),"")
```

However the problem is that there are multiple columns with this problem so this method is not very feasible option for me. Also another problem is that after this the cell loses the formatting.

Please help me resolve this, I'm looking for a Find and Replace method if possible. Worst case scenario would be a macro.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show what the emails looks like?

Comment: I'd like to inform you that the parcel in question has not arrived yet --- this is one of the cell content. Which is being copied to the Email body as following ---"I'd like to inform you that the parcel in question has not arrived yet".

Answer (score 1):

```
 Cells.Replace What:=Chr(127), Replacement:=vbNullString
    Cells.Replace What:=Chr(160), Replacement:=vbNullString
```

Comment: This was definitely what did it but I used a series of ascii characters to be safe. Now I am not sure which one worked, I used this list https://bettersolutions.com/vba/strings-characters/ascii-characters.htm Note how they indicate 2 characters for carriage return.

Answer (score 1):

Your cells in your excel sheet contains multiple lines of data within a data, which means all lines in the cell are entered with `carriage return`. (Enter Key)

If you copy and paste such cells to a txt file, you will get the text within a `" "`. The `" "` are not actually quotes, but text with carriage return.

Just use the formula and let me know if it works,

`=SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10)," ")`

[image]